# Assign IP and gateway from script file

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, routing

I have Ubuntu 10 on a VM managed with Vagrant.
I need to set at the boot ip and gateway so following information I found on vagrant github site I have added a script file to my vagrantfile.

The sh file looks like

```
sudo /sbin/ifconfig eth1 142.17.1.10 netmask 255.255.252.0 up
sudo /sbin/route add default gw 142.17.1.1 eth1
```

The IP I want the VM to have is 142.17.1.10 netmask 255.255.252.0
The gateway IP must be 142.17.1.1

Unfortunately, this is not working: the IP is correctly set but I have some issue with the gateway since I'm not bale to access the VM from the Internet.

VM routes look like

```
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
142.17.0.0      *               255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         142.17.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

and ip

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:74:ad:30
          inet addr:142.17.1.10  Bcast:142.17.3.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe74:ad30/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3224 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:133 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:266372 (266.3 KB)  TX bytes:8646 (8.6 KB)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to the script to remove the existing default gateway

```
sudo /sbin/route del default gw 10.0.2.2
```

and optionally afterwards

```
sudo /sbin/route add default gw 10.0.2.2 metric 100
```

If you want to use the original default gateway as a backup gateway (it has a higher metric, so the new gateway will be preferred).

I don't know about Vagrant, but an alternative way to do this might be to modify /etc/network/interfaces and add configuration for eth1 in the file as follows:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 142.17.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 142.17.1.1
```

and remove the gateway line from eth0, which will allow this to automatically start on boot the "ubuntu" way.

I note that this all assumes that you have 2 virtual network cards, and the information is supposed to go in the second one.

Comment: Yeah, my answer misses the point.  Fix your first line to become a delete and I'll remove mine.  By the way, we should not be provided answers that use the "route" command as their usefulness is time-limited given its deprecated state.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have update my script as you suggested ```sudo /sbin/ifconfig eth1 142.17.1.10 netmask 255.255.252.0 up
sudo /sbin/route add default gw 142.17.1.1 eth1
sudo /sbin/route del default gw 10.0.2.2 ``` but the routes now look like ```10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
142.17.0.0      *               255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
``` and I'm not sure why I have 142.17.0.0 instead 142.17.1.1

Comment: You have 142.17.0.0 instead of 142.17.1.0 because your netmask is 255.255.252.0, which means the computer thinks everything between 142.17.0.0 and 142.17.3.254 are on the same subnet.    I assume you would have gotten an error when you ran the script script - what was it ?  (It looks like the system did not set the new default gateway).